# CrytoJs.AES encrypt/decrypt in golang

Tags: go, encryption, aes, cryptojs

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
 
var data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
 
// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), 'secret key 123').toString();
 
// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
var decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
 
console.log(decryptedData); // [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
```

How to encrypt/decrypt in Golang that compatible with CryptoJS.AES?

Comment: https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-encrypt-decrypt-aes-tutorial/

Comment: SO is not a code porting service. Please post your most recent Go code and describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption strategies are generally designed irrespective of platforms. The crypto AES encryption you see is implementation of [AES Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in JS. Go provides it under crypto package. Go's documentation is good place to start looking code for [crypto](https://golang.org/src/crypto/cipher/example_test.go).

To speed up, here is an example:
Encrypt:

```
func encrypt(key []byte, text []byte) []byte {
    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
    gcm, _ := cipher.NewGCM(c)

    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    result := gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, text, nil)

    return result
}
```

Decrypt:

```
func decrypt(key []byte, ciphertext []byte) string {
    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
    gcm, _ := cipher.NewGCM(c)

    nonceSize := gcm.NonceSize()
    if len(ciphertext) < nonceSize {
        panic("ciphertext size is less than nonceSize")
    }

    nonce, ciphertext := ciphertext[:nonceSize], ciphertext[nonceSize:]
    plaintext, _ := gcm.Open(nil, nonce, ciphertext, nil)

    return string(plaintext)
}
```

Usage:

```
func main() {
    text := []byte("TEXT TO ENCRYPT AND DECRYPT")

    key := []byte("5v8y/B?E(G+KbPeShVmYq3t6w9z$C&12")

    secret := encrypt(key, text)
    plainString := decrypt(key, secret)

    fmt.Println(plainString)
}
```

Working example on playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/eg3-2dt39I3)
Note: Make sure to handle the errors as you like

Comment: The CryptoJS code _implicitly_ uses CBC and the OpenSSL key derivation function (KDF) `EVP_BytesToKey()`. Neither is considered in your code (though GCM is the more secure alternative to CBC). Especially the KDF is likely to be the bigger challenge here, if the OP needs a _truly_ compatible code.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I was just pointing out the that encryption is not relative to any platform. And I always try just to guide and not provide production capale answers here.

Comment: The only working code is https://github.com/Luzifer/go-openssl it can decrypt encrypted data from crypto-js. But if the data encrypted from the go side, the crypto-js side can't decrypted it.

Comment: Please refer to what @Topaco has said in comment. It might help since you want to handle encryption/decryption in both sides. But I wonder why you need such solution.

Comment: This simply does NOT answer the OPs question. This is just a generic reply how to encode/decode AES in GoLang, but is NOT compatible with Node, which was OSs question. Downvoted.